# Getting a SharePoint LookUpValue in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need help getting a SharePoint lookupvalue in my c# code

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

```
public static ListItemCollection GetData(string SharePointSiteURL, string 
Table, string Query)
    {

        ClientContext Connection = new ClientContext(SharePointSiteURL);
        Connection.Credentials = 
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        Connection.RequestTimeout = 3000000;

        CamlQuery QueryObject = new CamlQuery();
        QueryObject.ViewXml = Query;

        Web Web = Connection.Web;
        List List = Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Table);
        ListItemCollection ListItemCollection = List.GetItems(QueryObject);
        Connection.Load(ListItemCollection);
        Connection.ExecuteQuery();
        return ListItemCollection;

    }            



string SharePointSiteURL = "SiteURLHidden"
string Table = "Config - Clients";
        string Query = @"<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name = 'Title'/></IsNotNull></Where></Query><RowLimit>10000</RowLimit></View>";

        ListItemCollection listItemCollection = GetData(SharePointSiteURL, Table, Query);

        BindableCollection<ClientModel> _allClients = new BindableCollection<ClientModel>();


        foreach (ListItem listItem in listItemCollection)
        {

_allClients.Add(new ClientModel
            {
                Client = listItem["Title"].ToString(), //This works fine because its just a string.
                PrimaryMethod = (listItem["PrimaryMethod"] as FieldLookupValue).LookupValue //this doesn't as it throws null value exceptions and also this is a multi value lookup field and i have no idea how to handle this in c# code. say i want each value in this as a Collection as well.

}


}
```

So its just to pull the string from the multi value look up fields and return as a collection and not error if null. I cant find information on how to do this anywhere and i know it works as have the same code in PowerShell but it works as PowerShell doesn't care about types haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple lookup value, needs to build a FieldLookupvalue collection and then loop this collection to get multiple lookup value:

```
    var PrimaryMethod = (FieldLookupValue[])listItem["PrimaryMethod"];
    foreach (FieldLookupValue lookupValue in PrimaryMethod)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(lookupValue.LookupValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is a multilookups column you have to use this method to get the lookups values:

```
var items = listItem["PrimaryMethod"] as FieldLookupValue[];
foreach (var x in items)
{
     //x.LookupValue;
}
```